# if password does not match, then then user not redirected, rather it stays in the login page

Tags: node.js, authentication, redirect, passport.js

So I am retriving the data from a jason file and comparing them by brcypt and handling login using passport. When the credentials are correct, user can login. But when the credentials are wrong, it stays in the loading page and the page keeps on loading for eternity

Chat gpt is always saying I have problem in the postLogin() function, but I still don't get the problem. What should I change?

`passport.js`

```js
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const Users = require("../models/users.json");

const initializePassport = (passport) => {
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(async (username, password, done) => {
    // console.log(Users);
    const user = Users.users.find((user) => user.username == username);
    console.log(user);
    if(!user) return (null, false);
    try {
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if(!isMatch) return (null, false);
        return done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
        return done(err, false);
    }
  }));

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.username);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((username, done) => {
    console.log("Desirializing with username: ", username);

    const user = Users.users.find((user) => user.username === username);
    
    if(!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found' });
    else return done(null, user);
  })
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    // Find the user by ID in the database (e.g., Users.users)
    const user = Users.users.find((user) => user.username === id);
  
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found' });
    }
  
    return done(null, user);
  });
  
  
};

const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user) {
      // User is authenticated, continue to the next middleware
      return next();
  } else {
      // User is not authenticated, redirect to login page or any other appropriate action
      res.redirect("/login");
  }
};

module.exports = {
  initializePassport,
  isAuthenticated
}
```

`login.controllers.js`

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const Users = require("../models/users.json");

const initializePassport = (passport) => {
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(async (username, password, done) => {
    // console.log(Users);
    const user = Users.users.find((user) => user.username == username);
    console.log(user);
    if(!user) return (null, false);
    try {
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if(!isMatch) return (null, false);
        return done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
        return done(err, false);
    }
  }));

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.username);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((username, done) => {
    console.log("Desirializing with username: ", username);

    const user = Users.users.find((user) => user.username === username);
    
    if(!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found' });
    else return done(null, user);
  })
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    // Find the user by ID in the database (e.g., Users.users)
    const user = Users.users.find((user) => user.username === id);
  
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found' });
    }
  
    return done(null, user);
  });
  
  
};

const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user) {
      // User is authenticated, continue to the next middleware
      return next();
  } else {
      // User is not authenticated, redirect to login page or any other appropriate action
      res.redirect("/login");
  }
};

module.exports = {
  initializePassport,
  isAuthenticated
}
```

`login.routes.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require('../controllers/login.controllers');
const passport = require('passport');
const {isAuthenticated} = require('../config/passport');
router.get('/login', controller.getLogin);
router.post('/login', controller.postLogin);
router.get('/', controller.getIndex)
router.post('/logout', isAuthenticated, controller.getLogout);
router.get('/register', controller.getRegister);
router.post('/register', controller.postRegister);
router.get('/landing', isAuthenticated, controller.getLanding);
module.exports = router;
```

`users.json`

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "1",
      "password": "$2b$10$XSIbxEGItG/hJQwaMP48Fee0ZWmOhLp5dKMNPN2cImID4LV1Bz1sm"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am expecting a solution to direct the user to the login page if credentials are wrong without crashing